# Anchors with SafeHtml

Tags: java, gwt, xss

How would you use SafeHtml in combination with links?

Scenario: Our users can enter unformatted text which may contain links, e.g. `I like&love http://www.stackoverflow.com`. We want to safely render this text in GWT but make the links clickable, e.g. `I like&amp;love <a="http://www.stackoverflow.com">stackoverflow.com</a>`. Aside rendering the text in the GWT frontend, we also want to send it via email where the links should be clickable as well.

So far, we considered the following options:

1. Store the complete text as HTML in the backend and let the frontend assume it's correctly encoded (`I like&amp;love <a="http://www.stackoverflow.com">stackoverflow.com</a>`) -> Introduces XSS vulnerabilities
2. Store plain text but the links as HTML (`I like&love <a="http://www.stackoverflow.com">stackoverflow.com</a>`) in the backend and use [HtmlSanitizer](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/safehtml/shared/HtmlSanitizer.html) in the frontend
3. Store plain text and special encoding for the links (`I like&love [stackoverflow.com|http://www.stackoverflow.com]`) in the backend and use a custom SafeHtml generator in the frontend

To us, the third option looks the cleanest but it seems to require the most custom code since we can't leverage GWT's SafeHtml infrastructure.

Could anybody share how to best solve the problem? Is there another option that we didn't consider so far?

Comment: How about storing HTML **and** using HtmlSanitizer?

Comment: Thomas - May actually be very good idea. We just wondering if storing in HTML may lead in the long run to issues if we need to use the data for something else than outputting as HTML... (which is not completely unlikely).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not store the text exactly as it was entered by the user, and perform any special treatment when transforming it for the output (e.g. for sending emails, creating PDFs, ...). This is the most natural approach, and you won't have to undo any special treatment e.g. when you offer the user to edit the string.

As a general rule, I would always perform encoding/escaping/transformation only for the *immediate* transport/storage/output target. There are very few reasons to deviate from this rule, one of them may be performance, e.g. caching a transformed value in the DB. (In these cases, I think it's best to give the DB field a specific name like 'text_htmltransformed' - this avoids 'overescaping', which can be just as harmful as no escaping.)

Note: Escaping/encoding is no replacement for input validation.

Comment: Chris, thanks a lot for your input. I'm completely with you that this is conceptional the best approach.My question was particular if there are any existing building blocks/best practices how to implement the transformation in GWT. GWT comes out of the box with a lot of support for SafeHtml, which I would love to leverage but I don't see how to make it work with the links. Did I oversee something or is my use case just off standard?

Comment: SafeHtmlTemplates can help you with this: Take a look at "Parameters in URI-valued attribute context" in https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideSecuritySafeHtml#Creating_SafeHtml_Values You can also use UriUtils. You will still have to *detect* the links within the text though.

Comment: We went in the end with Chris' initial proposal to store the data HTML encoded and in plain format.